# Center circle inside the checkbox when hover

Tags: css

I'm trying to center the blue circle inside the square when it's hovered, but I'm not succeeding.

Could you help me?

```css
.container-checkbox { 
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
}

.container-checkbox input {
    display: none;
}

.container-checkbox input + label::before {
    content: '';
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    margin: 7px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border: 2px solid #999a99;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container-checkbox input:checked + label::before {
    background-color: #f39200;
    border: 2px solid #f39200;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-position: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0,0,256,256' width='14px' height='14px' fill-rule='nonzero'%3E%3Cg fill-opacity='0' fill='%23dddddd' fill-rule='nonzero' stroke='none' stroke-width='1' stroke-linecap='butt' stroke-linejoin='miter' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-dasharray='' stroke-dashoffset='0' font-family='none' font-weight='none' font-size='none' text-anchor='none' style='mix-blend-mode: normal'%3E%3Cpath d='M0,256v-256h256v256z' id='bgRectangle'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg fill='%23ffffff' fill-rule='nonzero' stroke='none' stroke-width='1' stroke-linecap='butt' stroke-linejoin='miter' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-dasharray='' stroke-dashoffset='0' font-family='none' font-weight='none' font-size='none' text-anchor='none' style='mix-blend-mode: normal'%3E%3Cg transform='scale(16,16)'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.857,14.844l-5.685,-5.812l2.859,-2.797l2.857,2.921l7.096,-7.095l2.828,2.828z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}


.container-checkbox input + label:hover::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #f3920048;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="container-checkbox">
          <input id="checkbox-all" type="checkbox" />
          <label for="checkbox-all"></label>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: The circle is sized much larger than the label box. Do you really want it "inside", or just centered around it?

Comment: centered around

Comment: I see that you edited your question to incorporate a working solution as I was posting my answer. That method is better than just eyeballing it.

Comment: Is this still a question? You snippet doesn’t have a blue circle, but the pale orange one appears centered around the square.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `top` and `left` declarations for `.container-checkbox:hover::before`. I started to say remove, but I think a value of -1px looks about right to me.

```css
.container-checkbox { 
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
}

.container-checkbox input {
    display: none;
}

.container-checkbox input + label::before {
    content: '';
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    margin: 7px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border: 2px solid #999a99;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container-checkbox:hover::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #007bff48;
    z-index: -1;

}
```

```html
<div class="container-checkbox">
  <input id="checkbox-all" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="checkbox-all"></label>
</div>
```